# GNU parallel is not starting every sequence i give him to

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use GNU parallel to start background jobs in parallel like this:

```
parallel --tag -j1000% ./cplusplus {} ::: $(seq 9001 9011)
```

Using --tag shows me what is being done, sometimes one job doesn't get started so it gets stuck in that point...
When it happens:

```
9004
9004
9002
9002
9001
9001
9005
9005
9003
9003
9007
9007
9009
9009
9008
9008
9006
9006
9011
9011
```

What am i missing here ? can the c++ file that I'm calling impact the next job to not start or they should all start independently of the outcome ?

Answer (score 2):

**Is is reproducible?**

If you use `-k`: does it stop at the same number every time? Yes: Try running the next number by hand without GNU Parallel, and then try running only that number with GNU Parallel.

Use `-u` to see output that is printed while the job is running.

**Is it intermittent?**

If it does not stop at the same job, but stops at seemingly random jobs, then something in `cplusplus` causes it to stop now and then.

GNU Parallel can help with that:

```
parallel --retries 5 --timeout 500% --tag -j1000% ./cplusplus {} ::: $(seq 9001 9011)
```

If a job takes > 5x (i.e. 500%) as long as the median job run time, it will be killed and tried 5 times before GNU Parallel gives up on the job. E.g. assume the median job takes 3 seconds, so if a job takes 15 seconds it will get killed and retried.